# Python, how do I drop the first octet in reverse zone? fun with strings

Tags: python, dns, ip, reverse

I need to create a reverse DNS entry for IPv4.

The ip address is 108.61.190.64

But the reverse DNS entry is = each octet in reverse order with the last octet dropped

i.e.

```
$ORIGIN 190.61.108.IN-ADDR.ARPA.
```

or

```
12.34.56.78 ->  78.56.34.12
```

Is there a Python tool for this task?
[::-1] does a complete reverse and not just rearranging the octets.

P.S. I have the same reverse issue for IPv6 but no octet is to be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do something similar to this:

```
>>> ip = '12.34.56.78'
>>> reversed = '.'.join(ip.split('.')[::-1])
>>> reversed
'78.56.34.12'
```

And if you want to drop the last one:

```
>>> ip = '12.34.56.78'
>>> reversed = '.'.join(ip.split('.')[::-1][:-1])
>>> reversed
'78.56.34'
```

Comment: It says I have to wait a few minutes to click the button. Thank you!

Comment: How would I drop the first octet?

Comment: reversed = '.'.join(ip.split('.')[::-1][1:]). You might want to read more about python list slicing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: @mine `'.'.join(ip.split('.')[-2::-1])`. Dropping the last one can also be done with `'.'.join(ip.split('.')[:0:-1])`.